# SUMPROD over a set and a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, math

In the documentation of Python 3.12, it said that sumprod(p, q) returns the sum of products of values from two iterables p and q.

I tried the following example in IDLE, with a set and a tuple:

```
ptup = (1, 3, 5, 7)
qset = {2, 3, 5, 8}
math.sumprod(qset, ptup)
64
```

It is an error, since 1*2 + 3*3 + 5 * 5 + 7*8 != 64.

I tried the sumprod() with lists and also tuples and they work well. I tried to look up whether set is not an iterable object, but the answer I got is definitely a set is iterable.

So what is the problem here? Can we apply sumprod with set and list or set and tuple?

Please explain for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is because a `set` does not have an order in Python, so even though you've written `{2, 3, 5, 8}` that could be *stored* in any order.

So in your case my bet is it is being stored as `{8, 2, 3, 5}` and then you get `1 * 8 + 3 * 2 + 5 * 3 + 7 * 5 = 64`

Comment: So it might be that Python converse it into a list or a tuple before calculate the sumprod? list(qset) and tuple(qset) both return 8, 2, 3, 5?

Comment: From the doc "equivalent to `sum(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, zip(p, q, strict=True)))`" if you print `list(zip(qset, ptup))` you get `[(8, 1), (2, 3), (3, 5), (5, 7)]` indeed...

Comment: It's possible that's the case that `sumprod` attempts to convert the set under the hood. As you say in your question sets *are* iterables, there's just no guarantee of the *order* in which you'll iterate over them.

Comment: You could also imagine implementing `sumprod` like `sum([aa * bb for aa, bb in zip(a, b)])` (where `a` and `b` are your iterables), that doesn't explicitly convert the set to a list or tuple, but you'll still likely get an incorrect result

Comment: @TomWagg I first imagine sumprod like the cross product of 2 vectors.

Comment: @trequartist **dot** product, not cross

Comment: @trequartista You can think of it as the dot product of 2 vectors, but that begs the question: how do you store a vector as a python object? Since `set` are unordered collection, don't use `set` when you care about the order of elements!